# How to check if a button in bootstrap modal window clicked using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a page which has a button. When a user clicks on the button, a bootstrap modal window will pop up. The modal window has two buttons 'Close' and 'Save'.

Based on the bootstrap website, 'Close' will dismiss the window and no action will be triggered to that page. But, what I want is when user click on the other button (For example 'Save'), some action should happen (By using PHP). 
If using php is not easy, then any other methods using javascript or jquery is also ok, but how to do that? 
Could someone explain how to make the Save button do some actions?

For a reference, I copied the codes mentioned in the bootstrap website.
JSbin link: https://jsbin.com/rebuwuvefe/edit?html,output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't use php to check a button click. Please teach yourself what `client-side` and `server-side` means.

Comment: @eisbehr is right. You can try adding event listeners to the buttons through javascript.

Comment: There are basic examples [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/) if you're going to use jQuery

Comment: @eisbehr: We can use php to check button click by keeping buttons inside a form. i know about `client-side` and `server-side`. I am more familiar with php than jquery. That is why trying to use php for this case.

Comment: What are you talking about? You **can't** use php for that. You possible mean to use php with the `$_POST` var, but you can't handle the button click directly inside your html. Thats what js is for.

Comment: @eisbehr I am not asking about how to use handler using php. I just asked how to do an action by clicking a modal window button using php since I am more familiar with php. Anyway I got the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with jQuery:

Add an id to your button element:

```
<button id="save-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
```

Then attach the event listener:

```
$('#save-button').on("click", function (){
    // do something
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot Pet Ibano. It works perfectly. I should learn JQuery :)

Comment: Now I am able to redirect to other pages and stuffs like that by using your suggestion and window.location commands. But again how can I link now this to php? Lets say I had a form earlier and when submit, it shows modal. Then I gave confirmation to save. How should I link the form values to php so that from there I can link to MySQL and save the form.

Comment: You might want to checkout Marvin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49687341/how-to-check-if-a-button-in-bootstrap-modal-window-clicked-using-php/49687473#49687473)

Comment: You can use $.ajax() method and place it on "do something" area.

Comment: Thank you :) I will try ajax() method

Answer (score 2):

I think you should reword the title of your question, as it is misleading to what you are really asking.

What you are looking for is jQuery's $.ajax method.

You can create a separate PHP script to perform whatever actions you need to perform on the database.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
// Assuming the save button is already set to the variable
// 'save_button', use the jQuery $.click method to apply a
// click event listener to the button.
$(save_button).click(function(){
    // Initiate the jQuery AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        // Method of request, POST (insert) or GET (select)
        method: "POST",
        // Location of the PHP file that connects to the database
        url: "some.php",
        // The data you want to send to the php file
        // Think of this data format as:
        // some.php?name=John&location=Boston
        data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
    })
    // Do this function when the request is done and a response
    // is received. The variable msg will contain whatever the PHP
    // file outputs (for JS interpretation, usually JSON).
    .done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Marvin. I wanted to check if I can do some action using php when someone clicks on the buttons of modal window. But like you stated, JQuery is suitable to do this. I think I will keep the title as it is for those who are thinking to use php for modal button clicks. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Simple jQuery example

```js
$(function() {
$( ".save-btn" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert('success');
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save-btn">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery click() method. I made a sample for you

```js
$( "#sample" ).click(function() {
  alert( "You can AJAX call or whatever you want" );
  $('#exampleModal').modal('toggle');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button id="sample"  type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

.